# Fipy doesn't seem to want to use SciPy as a solver

Tags: python, scipy, fipy

According to the FiPy website, you need "at least one of the solvers", and they [list SciPy](https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/documentation/SOLVERS.html#solvers) as one possible "solver". I definitely have SciPy installed - I can import it with `import scipy`. I haven't formally installed FiPy with setup.py or anything like that, I just have the code in a folder called fipy. When I then go into the Python shell and type `import fipy`, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "fipy/__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
    from solvers import *
  File "fipy/solvers/__init__.py", line 68, in <module>
    raise ImportError, "Could not import any solver package. If you are using Trilinos, make sure you have all of the necessary Trilinos packages installed - Epetra, EpetraExt, AztecOO, Amesos, ML, and IFPACK." 
ImportError: Could not import any solver package. If you are using Trilinos, make sure you have all of the necessary Trilinos packages installed - Epetra, EpetraExt, AztecOO, Amesos, ML, and IFPACK.
```

I've already tried doing this after formally installing FiPy via setup.py (using pip didn't work, I got some strange error relating to tensorflow). Setting the FIPY_SOLVERS environment variable didn't work either (same error).

I'm on Ubuntu with Python 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

Based on `File "fipy/__init__.py", line 44, in <module>` and `File "fipy/solvers/__init__.py", line 68, in <module>`, you appear to be running FiPy 2.1.x, which is quite old.

Please upgrade.